# Angular integrate google drive

Tags: angular, google-drive-api

I want to integrate Google drive API in Angular 2+ application. Can anyone has solution for to integrate it properly. I need help for integration.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your question is bit broad. What have you tried? If you haven't already, I suggest heading over to the Help Center and reading up how to ask better questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need Google Drive API credentials, which you can set up [here](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Then you need a Google Drive client: [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/downloads)

From there the rest is application logic, and will depend on what exactly you are trying to do. You'll need to initialize the Client, with the API key you've created in Step 1, before you can actually interact with the API.

[Here's a long tutorial discussing exactly this](https://hintdesk.com/2018/08/24/angular-google-drive-api-example/)

Comment: The tutorial link is broken.

Comment: You can try this: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-files